# Characteristics of stochastic integral?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I need to describe a couple of integrals which are supposed to be evaluated in terms of [Ito calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_calculus).

$$
I_1 = \int_0^t e^{-2\tau}dW(\tau); \\
I_2 = \int_0^t e^{-3 W(\tau)} dW(\tau);
$$

Here $W(\tau)$ is a [Wiener process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process). What meaningful information can (should) be said here besides mean and variance (based on the nature of these processes I think the mean is zero in both cases)?

I surely was able to do this a year ago but my memory is very foggy now. Your help is appreciated.

---

As for the mean it appears to be the case that
$$
\operatorname{E}\left( \int_0^t f(\tau,W(\tau)) dW(\tau) \right) =
\operatorname{E}\left( \lim_{\Delta \tau \to 0} \sum_k f(\tau_k,W(\tau_k)) (W(\tau_{k+1}) - W(\tau_k)) \right) = 0
$$
because $\operatorname{E}(W(\tau_{k+1}) - W(\tau_k)) = 0$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. You are right, mean and variance are the minimum, but they only capture instantaneous behaviour. Because you are talking about processes, their evolution in time/trajectories are also very important. But then there it is difficult to answer your question. What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @BertrandR When translated to English it basically says "For Ito integral $I_1$, $I_2$ find the distribution and its properties/characteristics". That's it. I am not really sure what is meant by distribution here (maybe these integrals are expressible in elementary functions), for characteristics I'd indeed be content with mean and variance.

Comment: Note that $I_1$ is a Gaussian process since $f(\tau) := e^{-2\tau}$ is deterministic. This means that $I_1$ can be characterized by mean and variance. Moreover, obviously, both processes have continuous sample paths.

Comment: To determine the distribution of the **process** $(I_1(t))_t$, say, where $I_1(t)$ is what you think, is another question--is this the one you are asking?

Comment: @Did I am interested in the former. I am not sure about interpreting these as processes besides imagining a bunch variables emerging over time $t$. How should I go about evaluating variances of these gaussian random variables?

Comment: @Did Why is $I_2(t)$ a Gaussian random variable?

Comment: @saz Oops. Thanks for the admonestation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $I_1$ is gaussian since the function $s\mapsto\mathrm e^{-2s}$ is deterministic, hence the distribution of $I_1$ is characterized by its mean and variance. The distribution of $I_2$ is more complicated but one can also compute its mean and variance.

Hint for both $I_1$ and $I_2$: $$I=\int_0^tH_s\,\mathrm dW_s\implies\left( E[I]=0,\ E[I^2]=\int_0^tE[H_s^2]\,\mathrm ds\right)
$$
Hint for $I_2$:
$$
E[\mathrm e^{aW_s}]=\mathrm e^{a^2s/2}$$
**Edit:** 
Note that $W_s=\sqrt{s}X$ where $X$ is standard normal and that
$$
E[\mathrm e^{aX}]=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb R\mathrm e^{ax}\mathrm e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm dx\stackrel{\large (t=x-a)}{=}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb R\mathrm e^{a^2/2}\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\mathrm dt=\mathrm e^{a^2/2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the hints. Following them I get $\operatorname{Var} I_1 = 1/4(1 - e^{-4t})$ and $\operatorname{Var} I_2 = 1/18(e^{18t}-1)$. I understand the first observation but the second one is still not clear in my mind (I tried to imagine this exponent in terms of series expansion), could you possibly provide any source or give an additional explanation?

Comment: See Edit. $ $ $ $

Comment: That will do, thanks again!